# Trying to search an excel file with rows in a column and find matching values in another excel column

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, scripting, openpyxl

So like the title says, I am taking a list of IPs that are being migrated and trying to find the ones that are being Load Balanced from an excel sheet that lists all the Load Balanced IPs. Below I (think I have) am taking the values read in the columns and putting them into a tuple for both files, then I compare them and put the matches into another tuple and for testing purposes try to put them into a text file. (Later I will put them into a column in wb3 and ws3). This is not printing anything. Does anyone know why? Please help.

```
wb1 = op.load_workbook('transition.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.get_sheet_by_name('Dependecy Details')
wb2 = op.load_workbook('mas.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2.active
wb3 = op.load_workbook('LB_migration_sheet.xlsx')
ws3 = wb3.get_sheet_by_name('Servers')

"""Extract Old Server IPs"""
iplist = []
for row in ws1.iter_rows('P2:P857'):
    iplist.append(row)

for row in ws2.iter_rows('C2:C5839'):
    lbips = []
    lbips.append(row)
for lbips in iplist:
    lbip = []
    lbip.append(lbips)
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as test:
        test.write(lbip)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that this is not a Python solution, but I'm a huge fan of using the right tool for the job.

http://spreadsheetpro.net/comparing-two-columns-unique-values/

Why use Python to do something in Excel when Excel already has dozens of inherent things to do this all by itself.